# Linux ADT Android Virtual Device startup issue

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

I'm running a version of Android Development Tools (ADT) on Fedora 19.

I had issues with Eclipse stalling on building the workspace - fixed that.
Now, starting an android virtual device prompts this error:

```
>Starting emulator for AVD 'testAVD1'
>qemu: fatal: Bad mode 0
>R00=00000000 R01=000005a1 R02=00000100 R03=0000000c
>R04=3fffffff R05=00000000 R06=006ec978 R07=000005a1
>R08=ec00000f R09=410fc080 R10=00000000 R11=006ec970
>R12=004a9928 R13=006ed990 R14=0000800c R15=00468888
>PSR=000001d3 ---- A svc32
```

Not sure what's causing the failure. I recently updated some of the Android SDK, otherwise no changes.

Any advice?

Comment: Does this happen on newly created AVD or old ones?

Comment: Morrison - happens on both new and old. Tried making a few different AVDs to test.

Comment: Just make sure Android SDK and ADT have identical version number release. Mismatch version numbers often lead to unforseen problems with Android. As a rule of thumb with Android SDK and ADT: If you upgrade one, also upgrade the other at the same time...